# Problem with error handling and get service

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to get Powershell to;
Be able to stop/start services remotely.
Log as it goes, so if it needs to stop/start the service, it prints that out.
But a big issue I've come across is if the service doesn't exist, it spits out a huge error.
I'm still writing the rest of the script, this will be doing a number of things in terms of shutting down an application, but I don't know if that error will mean the rest of the script won't run.
There's an additional problem in that I'm not sure how to also put the WriteLog function in the second stage of the script.
Can I just put multiple {} section after an IF, so I can run the Stop as well as write to log?

The below code is just for stopping the service.
So it;
1. Reports the service is already stopped.
2. Stops it, if it isn't.
 - Steps 1 and 2 work, if the service is there, it's 3 I'm having the issue with
3. If the service doesn't exist, I would like it to continue (Becuase it's not a problem the service doesn't exist) but print out that it doesn't, because they may prove useful to know

Note, the Write-Log, is a function to write to both a physical log file, and to the console at the same time.

```bsh
IF (Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -Name ('ServiceName') | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"})
    {Write-Host "'ServiceName' is already stopped, proceeding..."}
ELSEIF
    (Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -Name ('ServiceName') | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"})
    {Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -Name ('ServiceName') | Stop-Service -Force}
ELSEIF 
    (Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -Name ('ServiceName') -ErrorAction "Continue")
    {Write-Host "'ServiceName' doesn't exist, proceeding..."}
```

Right now this prints out the error 3 times that the service can't be found.
I get that this is because it's failing to get the service before it even evaluates after being piped, whether it's stopped or not.
So I think the method I'm using is wrong entirely, but not sure where to go with it.
I would expect nothing to be printed except 'ServiceName doesn't exist, proceeding...'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using IF statements in this way can quickly become out of hand. Also, you are getting the service many times in an unnecessary manner. You'd be better off using something like this:

```
try{
    #Getting service - This way the service is only queried once, making the script fast among other things
    $service = Get-Service -Name 'Service Name' -ErrorAction Stop

    switch ($service.Status){
        'Stopped'{Write-Host "$($service.Name) is already stopped"}
        'Running'{Stop-Service $service -Force -ErrorAction Stop}
        Default{Write-Host 'Service is neither stopped or running'}
    }
}catch{
    #Catching errors
    Write-Host 'Error'
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!  I've just tested that and it works amazingly well, I'll be doing some more research into try/catch I think.  In addition to that, will that just continue with the rest of the script if it errors then?  Presuambly I can jump out entirely if it errors, based on how well this works there are some more critical pointsi n the code later on where it would be useful to just stop.

Comment: Of course, done :)  Sorry about the previous comment, I kept hitting enter not realising it just adds the comment and not adding a line break!

Comment: @Khaelas If there are any errors during the try part of the script, it will break into the catch part :) Since the service commands don't return terminating errors (which is what try/catch requires) you may want to add "-ErrorAction Stop" to the Stop-Service command as I have done with the first Get-Service command. I will update my answer to show this :)